# Word 2007: Right side of equation bigger than lift side

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

See: [image]

As you see, for some reason the right side is smaller than the left side, eventhough the size should be the same. Can anyone help me deal with Word's stupidity?

Comment: Which equation are you referring to? I see one equation in the image, and obviously the right side should be bigger than the left side, as it is more complex. What tools have you used? The Equation Tools in Word 2007 do not normally produce things like this (e.g., it by defalt italicizes variables, as they should be here).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Right side, I used Equation Tools in Word

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I think he's referring to the fact that the right side of the formula uses a smaller font than the left side.

Comment: @Indrek, maybe, but the title says that the right side is *bigger*. And how was all this really created?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Title says so, yes, but the question itself says "the right side is smaller than the left side", so probably just a simple mistake on the OP's part. Fair question about the origin of that equation, though, I'd like to know that myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can aonly accomplish what you want by splitting your equation into 2 or more parts (sections) and create a separate equation for each part (section). Adjust the font size within each as you want to and then combine them on the same line of text.